# Disable user from running index action in specific controller using CanCan on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Below is my Ability file.

In most controllers, if I want to apply cancan, I just need to put `load_and_authorize_resource` in the beginning of the controller.

What if I want to make a specific controller called ABC, and not allow the user to run the index action (i.e. show)?

Any ideas?

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

  def basic_read_only
    can :read, :all
    can :list, :all

    can :search, :all
  end

  def basic_operation
    can :read, :all
    can :list, :all
    # can :edit, :all
    can :create, :all
    can :search, :all
  end

  def initialize(user)

    if user.blank?
      # user.role == 'guest'
      cannot :manage, :all
      basic_read_only
    else
      if 'admin' == user.role
        can :manage, :all      
      else
        # cannot :manage, :all
        # basic_read_only
        basic_operation
      end
   end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure the authorization is specific to the action level as well with [check_authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization).

#### ~ ... application_controler.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  check_authorization
end
```

If you have not authorized user X (through ability.rb) to perform action index at your controler, it should work.

Another option is only include autorization in the index resource:

#### ~ ... products_controler.rb

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base

 def index
   @products = Product.all
   authorize! :read, @products
 end
end
```

By the way, when developping CanCan Ryan has used [:read as an alias for both actions :show and :index](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/ability.rb) (...alias_action :index, :show, :to => :read).

Answer (score 0):

you can pass params to load_and_authorize_resource, ex:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:index, :show]
```

If you want to deny only index and show for class ABC

```
can :manage, ABC
cannot :read, ABC
```

I really recommend you to read the wiki it's very clear https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/